# Creating a centered, semi-circular cutout on a container

Tags: css, containers

I am trying to make a cutout like on this website: https://newspring.cc/about
Except that I would like to make the cutout a semi-circle instead. I've read plenty of answers from questions asking how to make full container cutouts, but nothing like this. I've tried for hours on end to figure it out, but I can't and I was wondering if someone would be so kind as lending me some of their knowledge.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you add a pic of what you mean by semi circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you looking for?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6bruzhjb/)

HTML

```html
<div></div>
```

CSS

```html
div {
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50% / 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

`background-color`,  `width` and `height` can be whatever you like.

Comment: That worked! I just modified it to this: div .cutout{
    display: block;
    position: static;
    background-color: #75B5FF;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50% / 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: -1;
}